# Double Inclusive Range step by step

Tags: c#, interval, ienumerable

I've written a method to obtain an IEnumerable from a start point, end point and step. Similar to Enumerable.Range() but for doubles and not fixed step.

```
public static IEnumerable<double> InclusiveRange(double start, double end, double step = 1)
    {
        while (start <= end)
        {
            yield return start;
            start += step;
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something, or there is a better approach?

Answer (score 3):

As this is a quit nice approach, it is missing an important part.

**Validation of input parameter**

You should check at least the `step` parameter if it is a positive number greater `0`.

```
InclusiveRange(1d, 5d,-1);
```

the above call is by your definition a valid call, but can lead to a **System.OutOfMemoryException** if combined with the `.ToList()` extension method.

You need to decide if you want to enable negative `step`. If you don't want to allow negative values for `step` a simple guard clause can handle this.

```
if (step <= 0) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("step", "The value has to be greater than 0"); }
```

But if you want to enable negative `step` values you need to add more checks and a different implementation.

A negative `step` means that start > end so you would need to introduce 2 more methods which you then call based on `step` beeing positive or negative.

```
private static IEnumerable<double> InclusiveRangeAscending(double start, double end, double step)  
{

}

private static IEnumerable<double> InclusiveRangeDescending(double start, double end, double step)  
{

}  

public static IEnumerable<double> InclusiveRange(double start, double end, double step = 1)
{
    if (step == 0) { throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("step", "The value has to be unequal to 0"); }
    if (step > 0)
    {
        return InclusiveRangeAscending(start, end, step);
    }
    else
    {
        return InclusiveRangeDescending(start, end, step);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of integers with Enumerable.Range() produces fairly agreed-upon expected behaviors.  But with doubles, you have introduced a mixed set of expectations.

Beside the validation of inputs as suggested by Heslacher, there is an issue of whether one would expect the `end` value to be included in the output.  Given the nature of doubles and given `start` and `step`, there is no guarantee that you will land exactly on `end`.  Maybe that's how you want it to be, but it is a new wrinkle that isn't in Enumerable.Range().

Also the name `step` is ambiguous to me.  I'd prefer clarification as `stepIncrement`, which should be a positive or negative double, and `numberOfSteps`, which should be a positive int.

Sticking with double step or stepIncrement, there is a wrinkle over whether a 0 step is allowed.  Heslacher's answer throws an exception.  Another valid answer would be to simply return the `start` and `end`.